# TwitterShareExtensionUIResources.bundle'. Couldn't follow symbolic link

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi I'm facing this error when i'm build the release apk file, by adding dependency in Package.jason file
"react-native-twitter-signin": "github:GoldenOwlAsia/react-native-twitter-signin#master",

Error:
node_modules/react-native-twitter-signin/ios/dependencies/TwitterShareExtensionUIResources.bundle'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.

Any one help me,How i can resolve it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have forked the library with some little bit changing kindly use this link

```
 https://github.com/mirzahayat/react-native-twitter-signin.git
```

hope so it will help you to solve this problem,
Two files are missing

```
 1: TwitterKitResources.bundle
 2: TwitterShareExtensionUIResources.bundle
```

i have resolve it by adding these two files in

```
node_modules/react-native-twitter-signin/ios/dependencies
```